# Open Specific Tab on Boostrap5 tabs pills - jsscript help needed

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-tabs

I cannot figure out the jscript part to show active the tab and its content based on a variable.
Code will be in asp.net core MVC. The view will receive a variable to show which tab should be shown and active.
Here is a simplified version of the code I would like to use: (ie: second tab would be shown in the jscript section).

```
@{
var selectedtab="tab2";
}

<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>To Dos & Done</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 d-none d-sm-block">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">To Dos & Done</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="content  ">
        <div class="container-fluid ">
             
                <div class="row">
                     
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card card-primary card-tabs">
                            <div class="card-header p-0 pt-1">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="custom-tabs-two-tab" role="tablist">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link active" id="custom-tabs-two-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-two-home" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-two-home" aria-selected="false">Home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" id="custom-tabs-two-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-two-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-two-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" id="custom-tabs-two-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-two-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-two-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" id="custom-tabs-two-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-two-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-two-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="tab-content" id="custom-tabs-two-tabContent">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="custom-tabs-two-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-home-tab">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin malesuada lacus ullamcorper dui molestie, sit amet congue quam finibus. Etiam ultricies nunc non magna feugiat commodo. Etiam odio magna, mollis auctor felis vitae, ullamcorper ornare ligula. Proin pellentesque tincidunt nisi, vitae ullamcorper felis aliquam id. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin id orci eu lectus blandit suscipit. Phasellus porta, ante et varius ornare, sem enim sollicitudin eros, at commodo leo est vitae lacus. Etiam ut porta sem. Proin porttitor porta nisl, id tempor risus rhoncus quis. In in quam a nibh cursus pulvinar non consequat neque. Mauris lacus elit, condimentum ac condimentum at, semper vitae lectus. Cras lacinia erat eget sapien porta consectetur.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="custom-tabs-two-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-profile-tab">
                                        Mauris tincidunt mi at erat gravida, eget tristique urna bibendum. Mauris pharetra purus ut ligula tempor, et vulputate metus facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas sollicitudin, nisi a luctus interdum, nisl ligula placerat mi, quis posuere purus ligula eu lectus. Donec nunc tellus, elementum sit amet ultricies at, posuere nec nunc. Nunc euismod pellentesque diam.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="custom-tabs-two-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-messages-tab">
                                        Morbi turpis dolor, vulputate vitae felis non, tincidunt congue mauris. Phasellus volutpat augue id mi placerat mollis. Vivamus faucibus eu massa eget condimentum. Fusce nec hendrerit sem, ac tristique nulla. Integer vestibulum orci odio. Cras nec augue ipsum. Suspendisse ut velit condimentum, mattis urna a, malesuada nunc. Curabitur eleifend facilisis velit finibus tristique. Nam vulputate, eros non luctus efficitur, ipsum odio volutpat massa, sit amet sollicitudin est libero sed ipsum. Nulla lacinia, ex vitae gravida fermentum, lectus ipsum gravida arcu, id fermentum metus arcu vel metus. Curabitur eget sem eu risus tincidunt eleifend ac ornare magna.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="custom-tabs-two-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-settings-tab">
                                        Pellentesque vestibulum commodo nibh nec blandit. Maecenas neque magna, iaculis tempus turpis ac, ornare sodales tellus. Mauris eget blandit dolor. Quisque tincidunt venenatis vulputate. Morbi euismod molestie tristique. Vestibulum consectetur dolor a vestibulum pharetra. Donec interdum placerat urna nec pharetra. Etiam eget dapibus orci, eget aliquet urna. Nunc at consequat diam. Nunc et felis ut nisl commodo dignissim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent imperdiet accumsan ex sit amet facilisis.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<!-- Control Sidebar -->
<aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
    <div class="p-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <p>Sidebar content</p>
    </div>
</aside>
<!-- /.control-sidebar -->

@section Scripts{

    <script>

 

    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to test the issue on my side with the Asp.Net Core project and I could notice that the line `$('#custom-tabs-two-tab a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');` is not activating the tab.

In further testing, I note that `fade` is also causing the issue. While using `fade` it is not showing the content of the tab page while using the workaround below.

If you could remove `fade` from your code then the below code example can help you workaround the original issue.

**Modified JS code:**

```js
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = window.location.href;
        var activeTab = "#custom-tabs-two-profile-tab";    // Specify tab ID here...
       
        $(".nav-tabs li a").click(function(){
            $(".nav-tabs li a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".tab-pane").removeClass("show active");
        
    });
        $(activeTab).trigger('click');    
        $('#custom-tabs-two-profile').addClass("show active"); // Specify content ID here...
    });
</script>
```

**Below is your modified test code.**

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FUT Player Cards";
}

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>To Dos & Done</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 d-none d-sm-block">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">To Dos & Done</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="content  ">
        <div class="container-fluid ">
             
                <div class="row">
                     
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card card-primary card-tabs">
                            <div class="card-header p-0 pt-1">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="custom-tabs-two-tab" role="tablist">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link active" id="custom-tabs-two-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-two-home" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-two-home" aria-selected="false">Home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" id="custom-tabs-two-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-two-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-two-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" id="custom-tabs-two-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-two-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-two-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" id="custom-tabs-two-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-two-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-two-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="tab-content" id="custom-tabs-two-tabContent">
                                    <div class="tab-pane  show active" id="custom-tabs-two-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-home-tab">
                                        <b>Tab-1</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin malesuada lacus ullamcorper dui molestie, sit amet congue quam finibus. Etiam ultricies nunc non magna feugiat commodo. Etiam odio magna, mollis auctor felis vitae, ullamcorper ornare ligula. Proin pellentesque tincidunt nisi, vitae ullamcorper felis aliquam id. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin id orci eu lectus blandit suscipit. Phasellus porta, ante et varius ornare, sem enim sollicitudin eros, at commodo leo est vitae lacus. Etiam ut porta sem. Proin porttitor porta nisl, id tempor risus rhoncus quis. In in quam a nibh cursus pulvinar non consequat neque. Mauris lacus elit, condimentum ac condimentum at, semper vitae lectus. Cras lacinia erat eget sapien porta consectetur.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane " id="custom-tabs-two-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-profile-tab">
                                        <b>Tab-2</b> Mauris tincidunt mi at erat gravida, eget tristique urna bibendum. Mauris pharetra purus ut ligula tempor, et vulputate metus facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas sollicitudin, nisi a luctus interdum, nisl ligula placerat mi, quis posuere purus ligula eu lectus. Donec nunc tellus, elementum sit amet ultricies at, posuere nec nunc. Nunc euismod pellentesque diam.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane " id="custom-tabs-two-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-messages-tab">
                                        <b>Tab-3</b> Morbi turpis dolor, vulputate vitae felis non, tincidunt congue mauris. Phasellus volutpat augue id mi placerat mollis. Vivamus faucibus eu massa eget condimentum. Fusce nec hendrerit sem, ac tristique nulla. Integer vestibulum orci odio. Cras nec augue ipsum. Suspendisse ut velit condimentum, mattis urna a, malesuada nunc. Curabitur eleifend facilisis velit finibus tristique. Nam vulputate, eros non luctus efficitur, ipsum odio volutpat massa, sit amet sollicitudin est libero sed ipsum. Nulla lacinia, ex vitae gravida fermentum, lectus ipsum gravida arcu, id fermentum metus arcu vel metus. Curabitur eget sem eu risus tincidunt eleifend ac ornare magna.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane " id="custom-tabs-two-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-settings-tab">
                                        <b>Tab-4</b> Pellentesque vestibulum commodo nibh nec blandit. Maecenas neque magna, iaculis tempus turpis ac, ornare sodales tellus. Mauris eget blandit dolor. Quisque tincidunt venenatis vulputate. Morbi euismod molestie tristique. Vestibulum consectetur dolor a vestibulum pharetra. Donec interdum placerat urna nec pharetra. Etiam eget dapibus orci, eget aliquet urna. Nunc at consequat diam. Nunc et felis ut nisl commodo dignissim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent imperdiet accumsan ex sit amet facilisis.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<!-- Control Sidebar -->
<aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
    <div class="p-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <p>Sidebar content</p>
    </div>
</aside>
<!-- /.control-sidebar -->
@section Scripts{


<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var url = window.location.href;
            var activeTab = "#custom-tabs-two-profile-tab";    // Specify tab ID here...
           
            $(".nav-tabs li a").click(function(){
                $(".nav-tabs li a").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".tab-pane").removeClass("show active");
            
        });
            $(activeTab).trigger('click');    
            $('#custom-tabs-two-profile').addClass("show active"); // Specify content ID here...
        });
</script>      
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Note: You could notice that I have activated the second tab page.

You could modify the code as per your own requirements.

Comment: your example is not showing any content when running. Maybe some issue with your sample code. Further, you need to modify the code above according to your requirement.

Comment: thank  you for looking into it unfortunately 
It's not rendering the content and the tabs properly using my example (cards + nav items+ pills + fade).

Comment: You could try to post a proper code example that renders properly. I could again help you check it.

Comment: thank you again - I have changed the original code that should display properly.

Comment: I have modified your code sample and tried to activate the tab page. Check my modified answer above to get detailed information.

Comment: The tab active works well now - thank you - However The content shown is always the "home" text content. Even when I click manually on the tabs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243859/discussion-between-lbrettsinclair-and-deepak-msft).

Comment: I have fixed that issue. Now, it will show you the correct tab and its content. Please check my modified answer. If you think the answer is helpful to fix your issue. Kindly accept the answer.

Comment: When I click any other tabs now, it still not showing the tab content.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using:

```
$(function () {
    var t = '@selectedtab';
    if (t.length > 0) {
       $('#myTabs a[href="#' + t + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```